# Humans best at long distance running: purely physiological or is it a function also of ability to pace?

Tags: physiology, muscles

I have read that although certainly other land animals are much faster over short distances, a human can run down any other animal over time, so that if a human is hunting like a gazelle, etc. eventually the human will catch up. I am wondering if this is purely a physical thing or if humans, knowing how to pace themselves, avoid exhaustion while the gazelle just runs as fast as it can and then collapses -- is it possibly because humans are smarter that they are better long-distance runners? (Now, some birds are able to fly for thousands of miles and I guess also in water we can't compete.)

EDIT: I understand that humans have some physical attributes that contribute to their long-distance abilities but is the ability to understand pacing also part of it?

Comment: there are studies of human biology which will list all the different physiology and ability-to-pace-iology (that's morphology?) specializations that make humans run long distances. I donno if you researched this at all, cos previous research is already good reading when you find it.

Comment: i will change question, because i have seen nothing about the mental aspects.

Comment: Humans are efficient runners, but just as a reference, I think there are some interesting answers here that call into question whether humans are really the best at long distance running. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/can-trained-humans-run-faster-than-all-other-animals-on-a-marathon-distance

Comment: While humans are certainly in the upper ranks, they are not the absolute best.  Sled dogs almost certainly take first place, at least in decently cool weather.  Horses are a bit better (as measured by endurance races over the same course, e.g Tevis Cup vs Western States 100), but it's close enough that some humans are better than some horses. But the real factor here is something you haven't mentioned: intention.  AFAIK humans are the only mammals (migrating birds are something else entirely) that deliberately set out to run long distances.